# Capitalising the first letters in file name

Tags: powershell, capitalization

Is there a way of batch capitalising the first letters in each word on files and/or folders. I.e dennis brown - love light (slow version).mp3 but I want it took look like Dennis Brown - Love Light (Slow Version).mp3?
Is this something that can be done via powershell?

Comment: [What have you done?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Comment: Having given the obligatory "Do some research and show your work" warning, I'll mention that the object that `Get-Culture` returns has a member  `TextInfo` which has some methods that you'll find useful. I'll also remind you that Windows is a "case-smashing" OS - that is, it preserves the case that the file name is lodged with, but considers upper case and lower case to be the same.

Comment: I've not tried anything to be fair, however I've searched everywhere, I'm not too familiar with PowerShell but have learnt what I know from this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, PowerShell has a built-in method to do this, using the `Get-Culture` cmdlet to capitalize a string according to your regional preferences.  This is how to do that for one string.

```
(Get-Culture).textinfo.totitlecase("some thing to uppercase".tolower())
>Some Thing To Uppercase
```

Since this can be hard to digest at first, I wrote a little sample for you.  This sample displays the new name of each file.  If you like what you see, remove `-WhatIf` parameter.

```
$files = Get-childitem -Path C:\temp

ForEach($file in $files){
    $CapitalizedName = (Get-Culture).textinfo.totitlecase($file.BaseName.tolower())
    $NameDotExt = "$CapitalizedName$($file.Extension)"
    Rename-item -Path $file.Fullname -NewName $NameDotExt -WhatIf

}
```

Credit to [this blog post](http://techibee.com/powershell/powershell-how-to-change-text-to-title-casefirst-letter-to-upper-case-and-remaining-lower-case/1235) for highlighting this technique.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the "Case-smashing" that Windows does.

Comment: Nice didn't know you could do that thanx for the post Fox